# Etymology of the phrase "goof off"

Tags: idioms, american-english, phrasal-verbs

It seems clear to be an American idiom with the approximate [meaning](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/goof+off), "to waste time or procrastinate."

My curiosity is about its possible relation to the Goofy, the Disney cartoon character.

Comment: [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=goof) says "goofy" came first: *goofy (adj.) 1921, from goof + -y (2). The Disney character of that name began life c. 1929 as "Dippy Dawg."*

Comment: Studying the hits from Ngram, it appears that the term first became indelibly published in the early 1950s -- there are several credible "hits" ca 1954.  ([The graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=goof+off&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgoof%20off%3B%2Cc0) shows the term starting around 1943, rising steadily, then plateauing around 1983.)  There are hints that it may have a military origin, but nothing convincing, and it's arguable that the term may have arisen from the business "efficiency" movement in its heyday in the 40s-50s.

Answer (score 4):

The OED has entries from 1932 of the verb ***goof*** meaning:

> To dawdle, to spend time idly or foolishly; to ‘skive’; to gawp; to
>   let one's attention wander. Sometimes const. off.

The first example which contains the composite ***goof off*** is from 1963.

The etymology is believed to be from:

> Apparently < French goffe awkward, stupid, < Italian goffo (Spanish
>   gofo), of uncertain origin

There are entries for ***goff*** in English from 1570 to 1878.

> 1570   P. Levens Manipulus Vocabulorum sig. Nii/1,   A Goffe, foole,
>   morio, bardus.
>
> 1678   Polit. Ballads (1860) I. 205   He calls the bishop Grey~beard
>   Goff, And makes his power a mere scoff.
>
> 1790   F. Grose Provinc. Gloss. (ed. 2)    Goff, a foolish clown.
>   North.
>
> 1801   R. Anderson et al. Ballads in Cumberland Dial. 18   My mudder
>   caws me peer deyl'd guff.
>
> 1818   J. Hogg Brownie of Bodsbeck II. 186   Weel I wat ye'll never
>   get the like o' her, great muckle hallanshaker-like guff.
>
> 1869   J. C. Atkinson Peacock's Gloss. Dial. Hundred of Lonsdale
>   Goff, a foolish clown, a silly fellow, an oaf.
>
> 1878   W. Dickinson Gloss. Words Cumberland   Goff, Guff, a fool.

The interesting thing is that ***goof***, ***goof up***, and ***goof off*** are almost entirely American - one seldom hears them used in Britain, Australia etc. I am wondering if ***goof*** may have come to America from Spanish?

Comment: This is a wonderful post. I'm only missing out some Disney references... just kidding... The only point that may be a stretch is the reference to Spanish. I'm a native speaker and have taken many hours of Spanish literature, read a bunch, etc., and I have to say that it doesn't ring a bell. But who knows, you may be right after all. Thanks for your erudite response.

Comment: @AntoniParellada  Your observation about the possibility of a Spanish link reminds me that the French also had a substantial presence in North America.  So perhaps the French word _'Goffe'_ is indeed the origin, and it may be that the path from _'goffe'_ to _'goof'_ can be traced someday in the current and historic language of the bayous of Louisiana.  See: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ac/Nouvellefrance-V2.jpg

Comment: @JohnMack English as well. There is plenty of evidence of the use of *goff* in English up to 1878. It then seems to vanish, and reappears again in America as *goof* in 1932.

Answer (score 1):

Sober reflection suggests the the passage of the word *'goof'* from the undisputed Romance language origin *'goffe' / 'goffo'*  to it's popular usage in American English was via Scots immigrants to North America, rather than a direct borrowing in North America from Spanish or French settlers.

The Scots word, *'guff'* also references spellings as varied as *'gouff'* (1822) and *'goof'* (1885).  *'Guff'* in Scots refers to a foolish person, or foolishness generally. The Scots National Dictionary Online gives details of the word *'guff'* here: http://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/guff_n1_v1.

In English (and Australian) the word *'guff'*  (as in *'a load of guff'* meaning empty and/or foolish rhetoric) is not unknown.  Seemingly the Scots and the US went in the direction of *'goof'* and the English for *'guff'*.

And in the 1930's along came Disney and a dog.